# Running HHVM's "hh_server" tool inside Docker container fails

Tags: docker, hhvm

Running HHVM's `hh_server` tool in Docker fails with following error:

`Fatal error: exception Not_found.`

Same tool works fine in the host with same OS (Ubuntu 14.04) and HTTP server (nginx).

Any idea how this might occur?

Comment: What image are you running?  If you created it yourself, post the Dockerfile or sequence of commands you used to create it.

Comment: Additionally to what Bryan said, please also post the full command you are running, and the full output of `hh_server`. Try setting the environment variable `OCAMLRUNPARM=b` and trying again, and post the output of that as well. Additionally, I'm very curious why you are running `hh_server` directly instead of letting `hh_client` deal with it for you.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem on a Debian image. After talking to a guy at hhvm's IRC channel I got it working by setting the USER environment variable to a username. Apparently hh_server don't work if USER is empty